# How to predict custom functions values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

[image: function in the photo]

There is this function, m=[12,24,168,672], the integer values of the function from t=0 to t=168 are known , as well as the fact that there are integers in the array b, it is required to calculate the following values of the function at t from 168 to 335, please tell me how this can be done.

Comment: Write first the function with no optimisation then look if you can compute the function using the values of t between 0 and 168 . Show your tried. May be t168 can be defined using t0 ie fct (n) = transform from fct(n-168)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from math import cos, pi

def f(t, a, b, m):
    # t is a number
    # a is a list of 5 numbers
    # b and m are lists of 4 numbers
    return a[0] + sum(a[i + 1] * cos((t / m[i] + b[i] / 24) * 2 * pi)
                      for i in range(4))
```

Now you can compute your function:

```
>>> a = [10, 11, 11, 12, 12]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> m = [12, 24, 168, 672]
>>> f(170, a, b, m)
15.671777368560361
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't know the parameters a,b , I should predict them, I have only values of function

Comment: @pipinstall then it's a math problem, not a programming problem :)